# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't set .CSHTML (Razor View Engine) as Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment, razor, webdeploy

I've been trying to deploy my ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta Application to my hosting. It supports all the necessary technologies and through trail and error I set the needed references' `Copy Local` to `True`. Then I got the error that my app cannot find the view. It listed .cshtml files it tried. I had those files in my project but they weren't deployed. I found that Visual Studio 2010 doesn't set .cshtml files' property `Build Action` as `Content` as it does for the .aspx files.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio automatically set .cshtml as Content, or will I have to set this manually to every Razor View I add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While waiting for the final release which will have full Visual Studio integration and Intellisense with the Razor view engine you may checkout [this blog post](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx) and especially the section: *Changing The Default Build Action For a File-Type*.

Answer (score 2):

My team has been running into this problem as well.  Even though we're all aware of the gotcha, it's too easy to forget to change the build action, and as a result you end-up w/ a runtime error.

I filed a bug on Connect to address this.  Please up-vote and comment so this issue gets some traction.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619539/mvc3-razor-views-and-partial-views-cshtml-are-not-marked-as-content

Comment: Thanks for the up vote, gliboran.  FYI, the ASP.NET team has fixed this bug in the MVC3 RC release.

Comment: I noticed this yes. MVC 3 RC really does add a lot more usability to Razor. From coloring, intellisens right down to the nice little icons :)

Comment: Oh, and by the way you're bug at Connect has been Closed as fixed :)